# Нужна версия php 5.4

Tags: php, хостинг

Мне нужна версия php 5.4, только она. я не могу найти как поставить ее на debian 8 или ubuntu 16. может кто помочь?

Answer (score 4):

Просто:

```
$ git clone -b PHP-5.4 https://github.com/php/php-src.git
$ cd php-src
$ ./buildconf
$ ./configure
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

Это способ компиляции с исходников

Comment: ./buildconf - ./buildconf: 46: ./buildconf: make: not found

Comment: @Diefair `apt-get install make` сам make установи

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так:

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5-oldstable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y php5
```

Comment: так не работает

Answer (score 2):

Используйте `phpbrew` - менеджер версий

Установите зависимости для `phpbrew`

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get build-dep php5
apt-get install -y php5 php5-dev php-pear autoconf automake curl build-essential libxslt1-dev re2c libxml2 libxml2-dev php5-cli bison libbz2-dev libreadline-dev
apt-get install -y libfreetype6 libfreetype6-dev libpng12-0 libpng12-dev libjpeg-dev libjpeg8-dev libjpeg8  libgd-dev libgd3 libxpm4 libltdl7 libltdl-dev
apt-get install -y libssl-dev openssl
apt-get install -y gettext libgettextpo-dev libgettextpo0
apt-get install -y php5-cli
apt-get install -y libmcrypt-dev
apt-get install libicu-dev
```

Установите `phpbrew`

```
curl -L -O https://github.com/phpbrew/phpbrew/raw/master/phpbrew
chmod +x phpbrew
sudo mv phpbrew /usr/bin/phpbrew
```

Инициализируйте `phpbrew`, обновите и установите `PHP 5.4`

```
phpbrew init
phpbrew known --update
phpbrew update
```

Сейчас мы выбираем версию PHP 5.4.34, Но можем выбрать любую другую из доступных - например 5.5.22.

```
phpbrew install 5.4.34 +default
```

Обновите ваш shell config file добавив в конец файла ~/.bashrc или ~/.zshrc (в зависимости от того какой шелл вы используете, по умолчанию .bashrc)

```
source ~/.phpbrew/bashrc
```

Смените версию PHP на 5.4

```
phpbrew switch php-5.4.34
```

Если выскочит `Invalid Argument`, попробуйте `phpbrew switch 5.4.34`.
Проверте версию PHP

```
php -v
```

[источник](https://askubuntu.com/questions/550191/install-php-5-4-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts-without-compiling)

[почитать до кучи](https://habrahabr.ru/post/210764/)

Comment: Там ответ был написан год назад, и не думаю что это актуально, так как вышел релиз ubuntu и в репозиториях уже php7, и php5-dev нету собственно....

Comment: @Naumov хм, согласен php5-dev выпили но phpbrew это ж всеравно не отменяет. Просто у него зависимости наверно сейчас другие инструкцию по установке можно глянуть на офф репозитории https://github.com/phpbrew/phpbrew . Нужно будет актуализировать ответ

Comment: apt-get build-dep php5 - E: You must put some 'source' URIs in your sources.list